# Building large scale IR/AI (information retrieval / Artificial Inteligence) systems with sqlite3

Tags: database-design, sqlite, information-retrieval, berkeley-db, embedded-database

*This question is to do with suitability of different database engines for IR and AI research. The two important questions are in bold below.*

I am loading a 17 gig plaintext corpus into sqlite3 using python. The line items populate three tables with a single normalization step of 1..* on average 5 entries per line. I have no indices on the tables. I am not batching the insert statements together, which I probably should have, but I am only calling sqlite's commit message after a million lines (so 3-8 table insertions per line). In hindsight I should have probably batched them together into 1000 values / insert. Commit probably isn't doing what I thought it would, it probably does internal commits every few entries.

The data loading started off CPU bound but now that the DB size is 33 gigs it seems to be IO bound.  both the plaintext corpus and the db file are on the same disk. I am assuming that sqlite3 is very conservative with pre-padding it's pages and is splitting pages left-right-and-centre now.

Anyway I will probably stick with sqlite3 for now, the advantage over a enterprise grade db I guess is the ability to create multiple database files ad-hoc and place the files on different disks. Traditionally I assume most people use postgres / Xapian / Sql Server or Oracle for this kind of stuff.

**From experience Is sqlite3 a hinderance for IR/AI system creation or a blessing ?**, I mean I haven't even created indexes yet and the data has been loading for 14 hours. If I am going to steadily encounter such huge loading times I might just stick to Sql Server for future prototyping. **I know berkeley db has a sqlite3 interface as well, and it should have the performance characteristics of a transactional mvcc database, anyone have any experience dropping that in for such problems ?**

**edit**

As James has reminded me, switching of transactions removes 2 synchronous disk writes from the equation, so I will disable the journal, secondly I will disable the synchronous setting so that the engine has the opportunity to insert rows at its own leisure, meaning I expect it to behave as if I was batching row inserts.

C++ might just be an all round better language to use for data loading (especially when it comes to 340 million rows of data), I expect a massive amount of useless cycles being wasted on memory copies and allocations. Correct me if I'm wrong though as it is quicker to write throwaway code in python.

Answer (score 4):

Just a suggestion but i would have thought with this much data (unless you have a very simple access pattern), any 'real' DB would seriously outperform sqlite3 (do test this though...), (milage will vary with engine type and system resources available - ram, cpu). Also - if you don't use transactions Sqlite will do a transaction per insert. Each transaction takes 2 disc rotations, so drive speed is the limiter here. Try doing one epic transaction and see how long that takes. If there is little risk of (or danger of data loss upon) the system falling mid data import then you have nothing to worry about and you won't need to commit every 1K rows.

I realise this doesn't answer your question fully but I hope it proves helpful.

Comment: Hmm should have disabled transactions, that solves one bottleneck :D

Answer (score 1):

What structure is your data in? It could be worthwhile having a look at some less traditional data storage options.This is slightly old article but it does a good job of showing some of the other options out there: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

As a follow on from the NoSQL info, have you considered going parallel with thinking? If you can have multiple datastore nodes that can all accept writes you can think set several jobs off to insert the data at the same time?

Even if you want to stick with a RDBS, i really would advise going with Postgres (or even MySQL) as they aren't much more complicated than sqlite and and bring far more features (including performance (dependent on usage)), you still have the ability to decide where the actual data file lives. If possible try to have the data you are reading and the data file you are writing too are on physically separate disks (i.e totally different spindles, not just different logical volumes) so the disk heads aren't thrashing about and wasting time. Even having the data on a seperate machine and attaching it via iSCSI (1GBbit) could quite likely prove faster.

The language you are using to insert your data shouldn't be to important (especially when compared to whatever you end up doing to querying the data) as all its doing is reading from disk and sending across a socket. (that said if you code is awful it will have an affect!)

Answer (score 0):

I have had phenomenal load speeds with BDB, particulary from C++ in embedded mode (i.e. no client server comms).
On old machines (8 years ago): 50,000 records per second.
Try it.